# Swift Sprite Kit Began Touch Function

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

Im messing around with an xcode project and I am trying to make a red ball SKShapeNode move around when I touch it. My own source code in the touch began class is not doing the trick. What is the flaw with my code and what do I need to do in order to fix it.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    //Rectangle Skeletions
    var leftWallRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 1000)

    var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25);


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        // Declare the Sprites in your scene
        var ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 25);
        let leftWall = SKShapeNode(rect: leftWallRect);
        let rightWall = SKShapeNode(rect: leftWallRect);
        let pin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pin");

        // Ball Properties
        ball.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        ball.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
        ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2 , self.frame.height / 4 - 100 )
        self.addChild(ball)

        // Left Wall Properties
        leftWall.fillColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        leftWall.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        leftWall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 3 - 45, self.frame.size.height / 2 - 400)
        self.addChild(leftWall)

        //Right Wall Properties
        rightWall.fillColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        rightWall.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        rightWall.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2 + 175, self.frame.size.height / 2 - 400)
        self.addChild(rightWall)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */

        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if touchLocation == ball.position{

            ball.position = touchLocation

            println("Touches");
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `-touchesBegan: withEvent :` being called? (set up a breakpoint to see if it is)

Comment: I checked and it is not being called. How do I fix it? @NicolasMiari

Comment: Typically it is because the property `userInteractionEnabled` (inherited from `UIResponder`) is set to `false`. However, the default value is `true` (at least for `UIResponder`; not sure for `SKScene`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL wow, this is a funny one,  `if touchLocation == ball.position`  I would be impressed if you can hit the exact pixel location of your ball.  What you want is this:

```
let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
if touchedNode == ball{
...
```

But personally,  what I would do is make a sub class of `SKSpriteNode`,  and do your ball's touch code inside this child's touch routine